# Avoiding spurious correlation in time series

Tags: time-series, spurious-correlation

I am investigating the relationship between monthly macro-economic variables, and monthly indicators of a company's performance and workload.

I am doing this for predictive purposes, and I am particularly interested in finding models that predict changes in the underlying trend. Both X and Y data are seasonal with an annual cycle (12 data points). I have ~4 years of data (50 data points)

If I am concerned about spurious correlation, should I de-trend the data, for example by using first differences, although I am interested in predicting the trend too? Are there specific techniques to fit a model to changes in trend?

This post is a continuation of [Finding all relationships from 500 independent variables to 400 dependent variables (time series)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165136/finding-all-relationships-from-500-independent-variables-to-400-dependent-variab) and 
[What techniques can be used to predict a time series with another time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164922/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-predict-a-time-series-with-another-time-series)